Proof that the infinity norm of basis matrix is greater than or equal to 1
Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $h,$ and let $\beta_1, \ldots , \beta_h$ be an integer basis, so that every integer in $K$ has the unique representation $a_1\beta_1 + \ldots + a_h\beta_h$ where $a_1, \ldots , a_h$ are rational integers. Let $\alpha^{(i)}$ with $(1 \leq i \leq h)$ denote the conjugates of $\alpha.$ Then one has the $h\times h$ linear system   $$\alpha^{(i)} = a_1\beta_1^{(i)} + \ldots + a_h\beta_h^{(i)},\quad 1\le i\le h.$$
Let $B$ be the $h\times h$ matrix with coefficients $B_{ij}=\beta_j^{(i)}$. Then $B$ is invertible (the square of its determinant is the discriminant of $K$).
Since $(\alpha^{(1)},\dots,\alpha^{(n)})^{T}=B(a_1,\dots,a_h)^T$ one obtains that
$$(a_1,\dots,a_h)^T=B^{-1}(\alpha^{(1)},\dots,\alpha^{(n)})^{T}.$$ What is the proof that the norm of this matrix $B^{-1}$ is greater than or equal to 1?

Which norm do you use (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), and why do you think that the norm in question is greater than or equal to $1$?

I am using the maximum norm. If
${\displaystyle \mathbf {x} }$ is some vector such that
${\displaystyle \mathbf {x} =(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots ,x_{n}),} $ then:
${\displaystyle |\mathbf {x} |{\infty }:=\max \left(\left|x{1}\right|,\ldots ,\left|x_{n}\right|\right).}$

So the norm of an $n\times n$ matrix $M$ is $|M|\infty:=\sup|M\mathbf{x}|\infty/|\mathbf{x}|_\infty$, right? Note that this norm is not the maximum of the absolute entries of $M$.

Yes, that's right.

For $\alpha=1$ we have that
$\max_j|a_j|\geq 1$, while $\max_k|\alpha^{(k)}|=1$. This proves that $\|B^{-1}\|_\infty\geq 1$.
